# BigNerdRanch android tutorial, ClassCast exception in geoquiz

Tags: android

Can`t really find out where is the bug. Application just crashes when pressing "cheat" button (starting second activity).
Throws classcast exception

GeoQuizActivity.java:

```js
package com.bignerdranch.android.quiz;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class GeoQuizActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 private static final String TAG = "GeoQuizActivity";
 private static final String KEY_INDEX ="index";
   private Button mTrueButton;
   private Button mFalseButton;
   private Button mCheatButton;
   private ImageButton mNextButton;
   private ImageButton mPrevButton;
   private TextView mQuestionTextView;
   private boolean mIsCheater;
   
   private void updateQuestion(){
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
  mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
   }
   private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue){
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
    int messageResId = 0;
    if(mIsCheater){
     messageResId=R.string.judgment_toast;
    }
    else{
     if (userPressedTrue==answerIsTrue){
      messageResId =R.string.correct_toast;
     } else{
      messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
     }
     Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(data==null){
     return;
    }
    mIsCheater = data.getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
   }
   private TrueFalse [] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
     new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
     new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
     new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
     new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
     new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
   };
   private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate(Bundle) called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
         mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        }
        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
          mCurrentIndex=(mCurrentIndex+1)%mQuestionBank.length;
          updateQuestion();
         }
        });
        
        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick (View v){
          checkAnswer(true);
                 
          }
         });
        
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick (View v){
          checkAnswer(false);
         }
         });
        mNextButton =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick (View v){
          mCurrentIndex= (mCurrentIndex+1)%mQuestionBank.length;
          updateQuestion();
          mIsCheater=false;
         }
        });
        mPrevButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
          if(mCurrentIndex==0){
           mCurrentIndex=mQuestionBank.length-1;
           
          }
          else{
          mCurrentIndex=(mCurrentIndex-1);
          
          }
          updateQuestion();
          mIsCheater=false;
         
        }
        });
        mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
        mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(GeoQuizActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
    i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        
   }
  });
        
          
        updateQuestion();
        
        }
 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
  savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
 }
 @Override
 public void onStart(){
  super.onStart();
  Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
  }
 @Override
 public void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
 }
 @Override
 public void onStop(){
  super.onStop();
  Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
 }
 @Override
 public void onDestroy(){
  super.onDestroy();
  Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
 }
}
```

cheatActivity.java:

```js
package com.bignerdranch.android.quiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CheatActivity extends Activity {
 private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
 private TextView mAnswerTextView;
 private Button mShowAnswer;
 public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.bignerdranch.android.quiz.answer_is_true";
 public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN = "com.bignerdranch.android.quiz.answer_shown";
 private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown){
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
 }
 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
 mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, true);
 mAnswerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
 mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
 setAnswerShownResult(false);
 mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   if(mAnswerIsTrue){
    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
   }
   else{
    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
   }
   setAnswerShownResult(true);
   
   
  }
 });
}
}
```

main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24dp"
android:id="@+id/question_text_view" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/true_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/true_button" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/false_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/false_button" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/prev_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/prev_button"
android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
/>
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/next_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/next_button" 
android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
/>
<Button 
android:id="@+id/cheat_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/cheat_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center">
    
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24dp"
android:text="@string/warning_text"/>

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/answerTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24dp"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/showAnswerButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/show_answer_button"/>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

edit: logCat:
i don`t know which line causes the exception or how to find it. In logCat, it`s in the 3rd line from the top.

```js
05-15 15:32:57.116: W/dalvikvm(349): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.quiz/com.bignerdranch.android.quiz.CheatActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.bignerdranch.android.quiz.CheatActivity.onCreate(CheatActivity.java:28)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-15 15:32:57.256: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post the logcat please and specify the line that is throwing the exception

Comment: Yes! Found it, thanks!
Line 28 
mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
lead to activity_cheat.xml, where i typed <TextView.../> instead of <Button.../>
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat is your friend:

```
...
at com.bignerdranch.android.quiz.CheatActivity.onCreate(CheatActivity.java:28) 
...
```

Apparently, you're trying to cast an object to some class it's not assignable from. Check the CheatActivity.java, line 28.